# handshake failure in ssl.get_server_certificate() during expiration test

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, x509certificate

I want to write a python3 script, that checks the expiration dates of several SSL certificates remotely. For most cases i can get a pem encoded certificate with `ssl.get_server_certificate((host, port))`

But in one case this results in the following error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:847)
```

if i try to get the certificate information with

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port 2>/dev/null
```

for a bash commandline it works without issues.

The server in question requires the user to authenticate with an user certificate and i suspect that the absence of said certificate is what makes the handshake fail. But since i'm only interested in checking the metadata of the server certificate, i should not have to supply a valid user certificate.

Is there any way i can mimic the functionality of `openssl s_client`
with a python module?

I could call openssl directly with `subprocess.call()` but since there are openssl modules for python it seems as there should be a better way.